# Indentifier Under Cursor Not recognized - Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, identifier

I have a macro I am running to update a report table in Excel but I keep getting an error on this particular line of code:

```
totalFieldsStart = Left(totalFieldsStart, Len(totalFieldsStart) - 1) & ")"
```

Here is a look at the entire Macro:

```
Function AppnSOFFormulasState(fTL As Range, fBR As Range)
    Dim final As Worksheet

    Dim aCol As Integer                          'index for appn column
    Dim dCol As Integer                          'index for div column
    Dim mCol As Integer                          'index for mdep column

    Dim appn As String
    Dim st As String
    Dim div As String
    Dim mdep As String
    Dim stateAdd As String
    Dim ntlAdd As String
    Dim totalFieldsStart As String               'cells to total will be separated
    Dim totalFieldsAFP As String                 'cells to total will be separated
    Dim totalFieldsOBS As String                 'cells to total will be separated
    Dim subFields As Range                       'cells to subtotal will be contiguous
    Dim c As Range                               'cell iterator

    Set final = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    final.Activate
    aCol = final.Range("A1").Column
    dCol = final.Range("B1").Column
    mCol = final.Range("C1").Column

    'set top left to be first October cell for APPN
    appn = final.Cells(fTL.Row, aCol)

    st = Range("state_select").address

    totalFieldsAFP = "=sum("
    totalFieldsOBS = "=sum("

    Set fTL = fTL.Offset(0, 3)

    For Each c In final.Range(fTL, final.Cells(fBR.Offset(-1, 0).Row, fTL.Column))
        If Not IsEmpty(final.Cells(c.Row, dCol)) Then
            'the first line will have nothing for div, so the range part of the next if will fail
            On Error GoTo SkipFirst
            If final.Cells(c.Row, dCol) = final.Range(div) & sTotal Then
                c.Formula = "=sum(" & subFields.address & ":" & c.Offset(-1, 0).address & ")"
                c.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=sum(" & subFields.Offset(0, 1).address & ":" & c.Offset(-1, 1).address & ")"
                totalFieldsAFP = totalFieldsAFP & c.address & ", "
                totalFieldsOBS = totalFieldsOBS & c.Offset(0, 1).address & ", "
            Else
                SkipFirst:
                On Error GoTo 0
                Set subFields = c
                div = final.Cells(c.Row, dCol).address
            End If
        End If
        If Not IsEmpty(final.Cells(c.Row, mCol)) Then
            mdep = final.Cells(c.Row, mCol).address

            stateAdd = "left(" & st & ",2) &" & appn & "&" & div & "&" & mdep
            ntlAdd = appn & "&" & div & "&" & mdep

            'AFP
            c.Formula = "=iferror(VLOOKUP(" & stateAdd & ",state_lookup_sof,3,FALSE),0)"
            'Obs
            c.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=iferror(VLOOKUP(" & stateAdd & ",state_lookup_sof,4,FALSE),0)"
        End If
    Next c

    totalFieldsStart = Left(totalFieldsStart, Len(totalFieldsStart) - 1) & ")"
    totalFieldsAFP = Left(totalFieldsAFP, Len(totalFieldsAFP) - 1) & ")"
    totalFieldsOBS = Left(totalFieldsOBS, Len(totalFieldsOBS) - 1) & ")"

    final.Cells(fBR.Row, fTL.Column).Formula = totalFieldsAFP
    final.Cells(fBR.Row, fTL.Offset(0, 1).Column).Formula = totalFieldsOBS
End Function
```

Comment: This may be unrelated, but I don't see the line where `totalFieldsStart` is assigned a value....

Comment: Where should I add it? The macro was working a few days ago. I keep reviewing the code and cannot find my error.

Comment: Well, using a text editor to search for all instances of `totalFieldStart` in the attached function only results in two lines; the initial declaration, and the problem line. If that variable is not being used in any other code, could you just comment out that line for now?

Comment: I took out the problem line, but now my data has a lot of empty rows.

Comment: Well, if you have a copy of the last functional version, I would recommend comparing your current code with that. Search for the `totalFieldsStart` variable to verify how it was originally being used; identify any changes made; etc.